# Finding probability that the product of numbers is divisible by $3$?

Tags: probability

This is the question given in my text-book

From the numbers $$(1, 2, 3,....,50)$$ two numbers are selected at random and multiplied. Find the probability that the product thus obtained , is a multiple of 3 ?

I have no idea how to do it can anybody help me

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $3$ is prime.

Comment: Hint: there are 16 numbers between 1 and 50 that are multiple of 3.

Comment: Hint: if $3|a$ then $3|ab, b\in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3$ being prime, at least one of the numbers chosen must be divisible by $3$. There are $16$ such numbers.

The probability of choosing *at least* one number divisible by $3$ is $1$ minus the probability of choosing no numbers divisible by $3$. Thus we have,

$$1-\frac{34}{50}\cdot\frac{33}{49}=\frac{1328}{2450}$$

**EDIT**: The above assumes that we aren't allowed to pick the same number twice, i.e, $1$ and $1$ isn't a valid choice. In case that is valid, our probability would be,

$$1-\frac{34}{50}\cdot\frac{34}{50}=\frac{1344}{2500}$$

Comment: I believe the 2 numbers picked could be the same

Comment: oh. they can? it's just my interpretation of the problem statement. it isn't very clear on that. i'll edit that in

Comment: I think the default interpretation would be that two distinct numbers are chosen. But for a homework question, out of caution one might want to solve the problem under each of the interpretations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did add both.

Comment: I saw that you had done so. What I was writing was advice for OP.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh okay. Cleared up. :)

Comment: Thanks @Sabyasachi, The question is with your first assumption and is totally correct thanks again

Comment: @Akash you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If either selected number is a multiple of three, the product will be.  How many of the numbers are not multiples of three?  You need to pick two of these.